# instagram api: getting user information and rate limits

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I'm a little confused if what I am trying to do is even possible given the expressed limits to the API.

My app should do this:

1. user logs in, app gets auth token
2. user gets list of their followers

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

this point is easy to get to, but the next step (3) seems potentially problematic

3. user gets the number of followers each of those followers has

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

If the user has 5000+ (limit is 5000 requests per hour) followers, do I really need to request each users information one by one? If so, it looks like I will definitely hit the rate limit.

4. user is able to delete followers having under a certain amount of followers (limit 60 / hour)

`https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/relationship?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`

So, it seems, given the limits, that such an app would be impossible to create. Is there some channel where I can request a limit increase? This tool would be used sparingly and infrequently.

Answer (score 0):

There is a section "*Relationship Endpoints*" where you can use request

**GET/users/self/followed-by**

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

to *Get the list of users this user is followed by*, so this is only one request.